# How can I shuffle rows in pandas, retain the index for future verification but after doing the test-train-dev split?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which I need to shuffle while knowing where did sentence 1 went for instance, before:

|  | source | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | source_sentence_100 | targe_sentence_100 |
| 101 | source_sentence_101 | targe_sentence_101 |
| 102 | source_sentence_102 | targe_sentence_102 |

after:

|  | source | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | source_sentence_102 | targe_sentence_102 |
| 100 | source_sentence_100 | targe_sentence_100 |
| 101 | source_sentence_101 | targe_sentence_101 |

Then, I want to be able to reproduce this. In order to accomplish this part, I know I can do:

```
df[:] = df.sample(frac = 1, random_state = 5).values
```

`random_state` would allow me to have reproducibility of the shuffle, and this should just shuffle the rows as I need. However, after this, I perform a train/test/dev split and I want to also be able to know if sentence 100 is now in the test, train or dev set but I don't really want the sets to have that index.

Basically, I just want to be able to keep that index list saved somewhere so that if I need to then figure out which sentence was used where I can just look for the sentence and know which set it was sent to and which idx it is.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, maybe do your train/test (etc) split into, say, df_train, df_test.  then save your indexes for them via `df_train.index` and `df_test.index` and store them somewhere.  Like to a CSV.

Something like:

```
df_train.reset_index()['index'].to_csv('df_train_index_save.csv', index=None)
```

The `df_train.reset_index()` copies the index to a column called 'index'.

Then `df_train.reset_index()['index']` selects only that column for the subsequent save to the CSV.